# Kivy/Python: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, class, object, kivy, positional-argument

I am not too terribly familiar with classes/class methods and how they work, and I know my code is atrocious! I wanted to dip my toe into the world of UI, and so I wanted to take a simple function I wrote in Python to see if I could create an app out of it. (Edit: The script produces a ":(" if today is not Monday, and a ":)" if today IS Monday.) (Double edit: this is my first post, I apologize for my ignorance re: coding and also Stack Overflow formatting.) We've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                          
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import datetime
from datetime import date
import calendar


today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
def findDay(self, today):
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%d-%m').weekday()
    y = (calendar.day_name[day])
    if y == 'Monday':
        x = ':)'
        return x
    else:
        x = ':('
        return x
    print(x)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
        z = findDay(today)
        return Label(z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

With the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/Users/myusernamehere/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "main.py", line 26, in build
     z = findDay(today)
 TypeError: findDay() missing 1 required positional argument: 'today'
```

I know this error arises from incorrect instantiation of an object of a class... but based on how I have defined "today", I am unsure what this means in my given context! (Unless it has to do with "self"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `self` only when you write an instance method (in a class).
For normal functions you don't need `self` in the signature.

This should work fine:

```
def findDay(today):
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%d-%m').weekday()
    y = (calendar.day_name[day])
    if y == 'Monday':
        x = ':)'
        return x
    else:
        x = ':('
        return x
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This then gives me "TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" which makes me think there still may be something fishy with the class? I may be entirely wrong there

Comment: Can you please provide the entire error/stacktrace? Which `__init__` call (from which class)?

Comment: `File "main.py", line 30, in <module> \\
     MyApp().run() \\
   File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run \\
     root = self.build() \\
   File "main.py", line 27, in build \\
     return Label(z) \\
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: I am SO sorry for the formatting of that comment, I'll try and indicate new lines with \\

Comment: I am not familiar with kivy, but the `text` seems to be a keyword-only-argument. Try this: `return Label(text=z)`.

Comment: That did it, thank you so incredibly much!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help. And yeah, the comment section is not designed for large blocks of code. But you can always [edit] your question and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this error arises from incorrect instantiation of an object of a class... but based on how I have defined "today", I am unsure what this means in my given context! (Unless it has to do with "self"?)

`findDay` is just a function, it has nothing to do with your class.

As you've defined it it takes two arguments, which you have named `self` and `today`. When you call it you pass just one argument (which is bound to the name `self`, the first argument), and therefore you get the error that you haven't passed 1 required positional argument, the one named `today`.

Since the function doesn't depend on anything related to your class, I guess you mean it to just be a normal function and you should remove the `self` parameter as it has no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't have a state, hence they don't need `self` as a parameter.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                          
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import datetime
from datetime import date
import calendar

today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
def findDay(today):                            # Changed here
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%d-%m').weekday()
    y = (calendar.day_name[day])
    if y == 'Monday':
        x = ':)'
        return x
    else:
        x = ':('
        return x
    print(x)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
        z = findDay(today)
        return Label(z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```